# Catalyst app info.plist not being recognized

Tags: deployment, catalyst

I am trying to submit my first catalyst app to the Mac App Store.  I have setup the App Store information in iTunes Connect, and I have confirmed that the info.plist in app has the following key in it:

```
<key>LSApplicationCategory</key>
    <string>public.app-category.business</string>
```

However when I go to upload to the app store I get the message that I need to add the LSApplicationCategory

> ERROR ITMS-90242: "The product archive is invalid. The Info.plist must contain a LSApplicationCategoryType key, whose value is the UTI for a valid category. For more details, see "Submitting your Mac apps to the App Store"."

I have confirmed that both public.app-category.business is correct, and I have also tried using the value "Business".  I get the same error message.  Is there something else I need to look at?

Answer (score 21):

The key which you are adding to .plist file is wrong. Add below key-value pair. Full list [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsapplicationcategorytype).

```
<key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
<string>public.app-category.business</string>
```

Comment: Full list here for anyone struggling with values: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsapplicationcategorytype

Answer (score 8):

slicerdicer's recommendation worked for me.  To add some additional detail, you can also set the App Category by going to Project / Targets / General.  It's the very first option.

Comment: This is the correct one. I ws manually adding it in plist and it ws failing.

Answer (score 3):

I had sucsessfuly upload two apps using catalyst then the third failed with that error. I found this and seemed to work.

To the info.plist add App Catagory with what ever catagory your app fits. I used Productivity.

Answer (score 2):

## 2023

Project -> Target -> General -> Identity -> fill App Category

[image]

Comment: Adding an App Category is a good idea. Adding solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was converting an iOS app to a Mac app, and I was updating the file info.plist, and it was not actually updating the overarching project.

I ended up having to go to the overarching project, under the left side TARGETS tab, I selected my app, went to the Info tab, and added the App Category there.